# Replacing lambda expression with method reference

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lambda, java-8, method-reference

I have a static method which takes the parameter `Stream<Double> stream`. Coming from either a `arraylist.stream()` or `Arrays.stream(array)`.

The method's job is to return the sum of all integers that are divisible by three.

`return stream.filter(i -> i.intValue() % 3 == 0).mapToInt(i -> i.intValue()).sum()`

This method works, however IntelliJ is suggesting the following:

> This inspection reports lambdas which can be replaced with method references.

I'm not overly familiar with method references, especially the referencing instance methods using class names scenario.

I have tried the following which gives an error.

`stream.filter(i -> i.intValue() % 3 == 0).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum()`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Since `i` is a Double, you should use `Double::intValue`.  IntelliJ not only inspects, but also proposes the change.  Just hit alt-enter.

Comment: If IntelliJ suggest such a replacement, you can direct it to *do* that replacement. By the way, it would be more efficient to unbox only once, i.e. `.mapToInt(Double::intValue).filter(i -> i % 3 == 0)`

Comment: @Holger does reversing the order not run the possibility of rounding doubles to ints, which are then divisible by three and change the result?

Comment: Your original code, `i.intValue() % 3 == 0`, already does exactly that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you said the parameter stream is type of Double, so you should do

```
stream.mapToInt(Double::intValue).filter(i -> i % 3 == 0).sum()
```

because you are calling Double class' intValue function.